# How can i create a popup for custom Choicefield and call it?

Tags: blackberry, custom-controls

I have created my own simple `ChoiceField` by extending `ObjectChoiceField`.. It is like..

```
public class MyChoiceField extends ObjectChoiceField 
{

    public MyChoiceField(String label ,Object[] choices) 
    {
        super(label, choices);
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) 
    {
        setMinimalWidth(width/2-62);
        super.layout(width, height);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        super.paint(graphics);
    }    
}
```

Now i want to display the my choices when i select `MyChoiceField` in custom menu(not the default popup that blackberry provides when user clicks on a `ChoiceField`)..

How can i achieve it? Sample codes will be appreciable..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Overriding the method **`fieldChangeNotify(int context)`** of **`ObjectChoiceField`** like this:

```
public class MyChoiceField extends ObjectChoiceField 
{

    public MyChoiceField(String label ,Object[] choices) 
    {
        super(label, choices);
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) 
    {
        setMinimalWidth(width/2-62);
        super.layout(width, height);
    }

    protected void fieldChangeNotify(int context) {

        int index = getSelectedIndex();

        try{
            VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();

            vfm.add(new LabelField("[Pop Up Content]\nChoice Field Changed #\n"+choices[index]+" selected."));

            PopupScreen popUpScreen = new PopupScreen(vfm){
                public boolean onClose()
                {
                    this.close();
                    return true;
                }
            };

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popUpScreen);

        } catch(Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Exception in choiceField fieldChangeNotify");
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
}
```

Use **`MyChoiceField`** now somewhat like this:

```
String[] choices; // Keep This Global
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.FIELD_VCENTER);            
choices = new String[2];
choices[0] = new String("Choice1");
choices[1] = new String("Choice2");
vfm.add(new MyChoiceField("Choise", choices));
```

Let me know whether this solution works.

Comment: Don't know what you wanted to mean by 'dropdown popup'... may be you wanted to mean the Choice List by that.    by your saying "I want to create a new 'popup'"  <--- I didn't understand that you wanted to make a Customized Popup Screen. I thought that "call that popup when i select MyChoiceField" was the main thing you wanted to do, and I'm sure the code I provided does exactly that.

Comment: i want my application to display my own popup when i click the Choicefield. like when we select choicefield for sex, i want to display options male and feale in my popup. Is it possible in blackberry?

Comment: like, the birthday in www.facebook.com. i want to show jan/feb/mar... in my own design. is it possible

Comment: @sujith, the answer seems okay to me as you explained your question. But now, Are are want a popup with your choices in it? If yes, then it is possible in BlackBerry. You have to create your own popup and invoke doModal(..) like method.

Comment: @Rupak.. I had tried for it.. But actually i had no idea for how to implement it. Can u guide me how i can achieve it? sample codes will be appreciable..